# overloading systemverilog system tasks

Tags: system-verilog

In all of our testcases, I see fixed wait() system calls. I need to reduce everything to small delays without making much impact. Is there a way I can overload wait task into my custom task and then call systermverilog wait to pass in smaller delays?

Thanks & Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

`wait()` is not a system task call, it is an event control statement. What you are asking would be the same as changing the behavior of `if()`.

What you can do is move the statement into a virtual method, then override the method where needed.